# Stopwatch I made using JS not working

Tags: javascript

I've run the code multiple times trying to fix any error I have found in the code but it just doesn't seem to work.

I'm using the *setInterval()* loop. The function does not even run once. What could the problem be?

```js
function stopWatch () {

  var hours = Number(document.getElementById('hours').innerHTML);
  var minutes = Number(document.getElementById('minutes').innerHTML);
  var seconds = Number(document.getElementById('seconds').innerHTML);

  if (seconds<60) {
    seconds++
  } else {
    seconds = 0;
    minutes++
  }

  if (minutes == 60) {
    minutes = 0;
    hours++
  }

  if (seconds.length==2) {
    document.getElementById('seconds').innerHTML = seconds;
  } else {
    document.getElementById('seconds').innerHTML = '0' + seconds;
  }

  if (minutes.length==2) {
    document.getElementById('minutes').innerHTML = minutes;
  } else {
    document.getElementById('minutes').innerHTML = '0' + minutes;
  }

  if (hours.length==2) {
    document.getElementById('hours').innerHTML = hours;
  }

  if (hours.length==1) {
    document.getElementById('hours').innerHTML = '0' + hours;
  }
  
 }

setInterval(stopWatch,1000)
```

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <p>
        <span id='hours'>00</span>:<span id='minutes'>00</span>:<span id='seconds'>00</span>
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code only runs once. You need to use a loop of some description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code only runs once. You need to use a loop of some description.

There are many ways to do this. A simple example would be to use `setInterval` to call the inners of your function every second.

You also have an error in your logic. You shouldn't be checking the length of the number (`seconds.length==2`). You should check wether the number is greater than `9` (`seconds > 9`):

```js
function stopWatch() {

  setInterval(function() {

    var hours = Number(document.getElementById('hours').innerHTML);
    var minutes = Number(document.getElementById('minutes').innerHTML);
    var seconds = Number(document.getElementById('seconds').innerHTML);

    if (seconds < 60) {
      seconds++
    } else {
      seconds = 0;
      minutes++
    }

    if (minutes == 60) {
      minutes = 0;
      hours++
    }

    if (seconds > 9) {
      document.getElementById('seconds').innerHTML = seconds;
    } else {
      document.getElementById('seconds').innerHTML = '0' + seconds;
    }

    if (minutes > 9) {
      document.getElementById('minutes').innerHTML = minutes;
    } else {
      document.getElementById('minutes').innerHTML = '0' + minutes;
    }

    if (hours > 9) {
      document.getElementById('hours').innerHTML = hours;
    } else {
        document.getElementById('hours').innerHTML = '0' + hours;
    }

  }, 1000);

}

stopWatch()
```

```html
<html>

<head></head>

<body>
  <p>
    <span id='hours'>00</span>:<span id='minutes'>00</span>:<span id='seconds'>00</span>
  </p>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You mean why the stopwatch is not running?
You should wrap it in a setInteraval for it to update every second:

```
setInterval(function() {
   stopWatch()
},1000);
```